# Change Property Name in DataGridView

Tags: c#, list, winforms, datagridview, alias

I have a human list that I want to change the name of its properties while adding a record to it.

```
list<Human> HumansList = new list<Human>();

foreach(ListViewItem item in ListView.Items)
{
    HumansList.Add(new Human{Name = item.subitems[1].text});
}
```

i want ***before*** top code,change the property whose name is `Name` to `Name Of Guest` for example to use for datagridview ***column header***.in another word i want something like ***alias*** for my class's properties and When I display my list in Datagrid, the names of the columns should be different from the names of the properties and their value should be the same as the one I specified.

i try `ExpandoObject` and `IDictionary` too but i don't know how this work exactly?

what should i do it?

Comment: The following may be helpul [Inheritance - derive types to create more specialized behavior](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/fundamentals/object-oriented/inheritance) and [Inheritance in C# and .NET](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/fundamentals/tutorials/inheritance)

Comment: You can't name a property `Name Of Guest` because it contains spaces.

Comment: how you get the name of the property sofar

Comment: @user9938 i would use it for datagrid column header and stimulsoft too

Comment: @spzvtbg I didn't understand exactly what you meant,If I understand correctly i get value of property from listviewitem

Comment: @Saber - it's not clear to me why you whant to rename the class property at runtime. if your question is how do you can  customize the headers - there are alredy answers in SO, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27267176/changing-datagridview-header-text-at-runtime,

Comment: It looks like you are looking for `[DisplayName]` attribute.

Comment: @RezaAghaei how can i do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i think `[DisplayName]` can handle my qustion.you can see more information on this [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.componentmodel.displaynameattribute?view=net-6.0).

Comment: thanks to @Reza Aghaei.